# Block access to folder outside of PHP in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, block

I have the following structure on my project

```
assets
    css
    js
    img
    ........
caches
    x-cache
    y-cache
    ........
resources
    config.php
    libraries
    pages
    ........
 index.php
 .htaccess
```

Basically, I use assets and resources/pages to display pages. And I don't want other files such as config.php as accessible from a user. So, I'm asking how can I make these files/folders available only by PHP code? How can I redirect users to the index page?

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file in each of the folders and call it index.php
put d following code inside the index.php file

```
<?php
header('Location:../');
?>
```

if any user try to visit www.sitename.com/assets they will be redirected to the super folder index.php file. Same as the /resources folder.
For folders inside folders use

```
<?php
    header('Location:../../');
    ?>
```

Now, for files like config.php use a php session on each of the files

```
<?php session_start();
if(!isset(mySessionValue)){
header('Location:sitenam.com/index.php');
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root you can block (or redirect) any direct access to certain directories/files using mod_rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above would send a 403 Forbidden for any URLs (ie. direct requests from the user) that start `/resources`.

Sending a 403 would be the preferred response, however, if you wanted to redirect the user to the index page, change the above `RewriteRule` to read:

```
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]
```